# Change What the Tooltip Says When You Drag a File over a Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the tooltip text that displays when you drag a file over a drop zone on a webpage? By default, it says "Move," e.g.:

[image]

I'm developing a JavaScript web app and would like to change what it says to something more meaningful to my app. Is it possible to do it with CSS or is JavaScript necessary?

Comment: This looks like it's built in with the OS so I think it's impossible.

Comment: The Google Drive web app, for example, changes the text when dragging something, so it should be possible to do.

Comment: That's within the browser, so yes it will work dragging from a page you own to a dropzone you own, but dragging from a folder on the computer is handled by the OS like Phiter said.

Comment: @SvenWritesCode In the Google Drive web app, it changes the text when I drop something from my desktop onto the browser. Instead of saying "Move," it says "Copy."

Answer (score 3):

The message is handled by the OS, but you can change the effect by setting [`event.dataTransfer.dropEffect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect) to one of the following options:

- **copy**

  > A copy of the source item is made at the new location.
- **move**

  > An item is moved to a new location.
- **link**

  > A link is established to the source at the new location.
- **none**

  > The item may not be dropped.

See this example:

```js
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
var select = document.getElementById('effectSelect');

dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = select.value;
});

dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px dashed #aaaaaa;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
Select the effect:

<select id="effectSelect">
    <option value="copy">copy</option>
    <option value="move">move</option>
    <option value="link">link</option>
    <option value="none">none</option>
</select>
<div id="drop-zone">Drag anything from your OS here</div>
```

You can get more information on `dataTransfer` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer).